# How to measure similarity of inner observation variation without considering actual values?

Tags: python, r, covariance, variance

I am sure that this has been done before but I am unsure of how to even phrase the question for google and have been racking my brain for a few hours now, but I can explain it with an example. Imagine you have the data below.

| observation # | m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | m5 | m6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | L | T | L | T | L |
| 2 | A | R | A | R | A | A |
| 3 | B | C | B | C | B | C |
| 4 | K | K | K | A | L | K |
| 5 | P | P | P | R | L | P |

I want to generate some sort of similarity metric between observations that relates to the variation across the m1-6 variables. The actual values in the cells shouldn't matter at all.

Considering the table above, for example observations 1 and 3 are exactly the same as they vary the same across the m's (TLTLTL & BCBCBC). 1 & 3 are very similar to 2, and observations 4 and 5 are the same but not similar to 1-3.

I would like an output that captures all these relationships for example . . .

| observation # | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.8 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 0.8 | 1 | 0.8 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.8 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 4 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 1 | 1 |

A few notes - each cell can have more than just 1 letter but again the actual contents of each cell don't matter - just the variation across the m's within each observation compared to other observations. Is their a name for what I am trying to do here? Also I only know python & R so if you provide any code please have it in those (python preferred).

It is driving me crazy that I can't figure this out. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: *"Is their a name for what I am trying to do here?"* You are trying to compute a distance matrix with a custom distance function. Your distance function might be something like `dist(x, y) = mean(x == y)`

Comment: But I'm pretty unsure about your distance metric... I get that obs 1 and obs 3 are the same, so they get a 1. I'm not sure of a good way to classify the similarity between "TLTLTL" and "ARARAA". You might want to read about common [string distance metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). It seems like maybe you want a modified Levenshtein distance, where a "find/replace" is used instead of a single character substitution. You might have to implement that yourself...

Comment: (And I should clarify, seems like you want a similarity matrix, not a distance matrix, but they're closely enough related that if you can get one the other should be easy.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the response and the clarification - this definitely helps give me some things to look into to help me solve my problem! The problem I still have is when I look into string (approximate/fuzzy) matching the actual values (letters) are important - I really want to compare similarity/difference of the variation which to me seems conceptually separate from string matching in my head - I think a modified Levenshtein dist could help, but I am still unsure how to capture the 'shape' of each observation instead of the actual values (if that makes sense)

Comment: Agreed - it's hard. I haven't seen anything like it before. And there's a lot of possibilities--"abcd" has the same shape as "wxyz", but what about "aaba" vs "xyyx"? What about "aaaa" vs "xxyy"? Is it symmetric? Is "aaaa" as close to "xxyy" as "xxyy" is to "aaaa"? What you want is certainly not a common similarity/distance metric, so you might need to do a real deep dive of string distance metrics to find something or else roll your own.

Comment: So it should be symmetric - what also makes it difficult is that the distance between "aabc" and "xxyz" and "aayz" is all the same (0) as in there is no 'global' significance of the letters - each relationship should be looked at 1 to 1. Also making things more difficult is that no letter pairing should have more weight than any other. My first attempt was to try to match letters - so to set first two observations as same then next two different letters respectivly as the same and so on, but this makes "abbbb" and "xxxxx" look more different than I want them to be.

Comment: Thanks again though I will share my solution when I get to one - although right now I am thinking about matching up the most possible paired letters, setting those as the same. Then doing second most, then setting them as the same, and so on. Although I can see this turning into a computational headache and being absurdly slow.